# Find a json key into a parsed object

Tags: json, parsing, key

I have a long json file, that has a lot objet with a lot of keys. One of these keys/value is unike into the json file: "label":"Ticket Date".

I can find the object that contains these key/value ussing this script that i found in internet

```
function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
           objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
               
        }else 
        //if key matches and value matches or if key matches and value is not passed (eliminating the case where key matches but passed value does not)
          if (i == key && obj[i] == val || i == key && val == '') { //
            // objects = Object.entries(obj[i]);
             objects.push(obj);
                        
          } else if (obj[i] == val &&  key == ''){
            //only add if the object is not already in the array
            if (objects.lastIndexOf(obj) == -1){
               objects.push(obj)
            }
          }
    }       
    return objects
    
}
```

It return this

`[{options={enable_time=false, enable_date=true, is_mandatory=true}, parent_id=f3245d39-ea77-11e1-aff1-0800200c9a66, label=Ticket Date, type=datetime, responses={datetime=2022-07-21T15:18:26.000Z}, item_id=b9e190b9-db05-4769-bef5-d7de541e2156}]`

Now I need get the value that has other key on objects called "responses" (in this case, but may be other key has not a fixed value lenght). The problem is the objects variable has not a json format.
I have this other script that return the value of a key, but it need that be in jsonformat

```
//return an array of values that match on a certain key
function getValues(obj, key) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getValues(obj[i], key));
        } else if (i == key) {
            objects.push(obj[i]);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
```

Is any other way to get a variable with json format ???

Thanks a lot in advance

Omar

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sorry. Both functions works well.
The problem was that I have used the key 'responses' instead of 'datetime' to get the timestamp of the regord

I'm sorry again.

Omar